# What number is the pad token for huggingface models?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, huggingface

I am running these lines of code:

```
x = "A"
tokenizer = LlamaTokenizer.from_pretrained("meta-llama/Llama-2-7b-chat-hf")
tokenizer.add_special_tokens({'pad_token': '[PAD]'})

tokenized_text = tokenizer(x, return_tensors="pt", padding='max_length', max_length=10, truncation=True)
print(tokenized_text)
```

However, the tokenizer ends up padding with the number 32000. This then causes the embedding layer of the llama model to go out of range when indexing with the tokens. I know I can use eos token but I am confused on why the padding token number is set beyond the size of the embedding layer dictionary.